# Error while building images for plugins in Sahara (devStack Pike) ERROR: venv: commands failed

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, devstack

**Configuration:** Openstack Pike using devStack on Ubuntu16.04 VM

**Plugins enabled:**

- Sahara
- Heat
- Trove
- Sahara Dashboard
- Trove Dashboard

The install was successful and was able to access horizon. Now, trying to build images for Sahara by following these steps:

1. Clone repository “https://github.com/openstack/sahara-image-elements” locally.
2. Use tox to build images.

When I run the command in the folder /sahara-image-elements

```
stack@devstack:~/sahara-image-elements$ tox -e venv -- sahara-image-create -u
```

The following error is throwing up

```
dib-run-parts Thu Nov 23 16:29:59 EST 2017 0-check-hadoop completed
dib-run-parts Thu Nov 23 16:29:59 EST 2017 Running /tmp/dib_build.6egsQeuH/hooks/root.d/0-check-hive
dib-run-parts Thu Nov 23 16:29:59 EST 2017 0-check-hive completed
dib-run-parts Thu Nov 23 16:29:59 EST 2017 Running /tmp/dib_build.6egsQeuH/hooks/root.d/0-check-oozie
dib-run-parts Thu Nov 23 16:29:59 EST 2017 0-check-oozie completed
dib-run-parts Thu Nov 23 16:29:59 EST 2017 Running /tmp/dib_build.6egsQeuH/hooks/root.d/0-check-spark
/tmp/dib_build.6egsQeuH/hooks/root.d/0-check-spark: line 23: DIB_SPARK_VERSION: unbound variable
2017-11-23 16:29:59.868 INFO diskimage_builder.block_device.blockdevice [-] State already cleaned - no way to do anything here
ERROR: InvocationError: '/opt/stack/sahara-image-elements/.tox/venv/bin/sahara-image-create'
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary ________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   venv: commands failed
```

Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

set DIB_SPARK_VERSION=2.3.0 or 2.2.0 in your environment variable and source it then run same command. if same error occurs remove -u and add run this command tox -e venv -- sahara-image-create -i ubuntu -p spark -s 2.3.0